# Doctrine ODM Distinct With Limit

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have the following problem: I can't limit number of results when using distinct. Exemple :

```
$stores = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('Application\Document\Item')
   ->distinct('storeName')
   ->limit(10)
   ->getQuery()
   ->execute();
```

This query render 100 entries but I want only 10 results.

Answer (score 1):

With query builder class in `ORM` you need to use:

```
->setMaxResults(10);
```

As per @Siol and @john Smith said, in `ODM` you could use limit:

```
->limit(10);
```

Comment: setMaxResults() is only for Doctrine ORM and not ODM

Comment: for 
ODM\MongoDB\Query\Builder its just ->limit(1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think distinct will work with limit as suggested in the Jira mongodb issue ticket **[Ability to use Limit() with Distinct()](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2130)**:

> The current Distinct() implementation only allows for bringing back
>   ALL distinct values in the collection or matching a query, but there
>   is no way to limit these results. This would be very convenient and
>   there are many use cases.